# XAML displaying system message when using datatemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

When trying to create a simple datatemplate to change the visibility of a text block from collapsed to visible my window is displaying the text;

```
System.windows.DataTemplate
```

And nothing else.

My code;

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Name="one" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">One</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Visibility="Collapsed" Name="two" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">Two</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.isCorrect}" Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="one" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.isCorrect}" Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="two" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

isCorrect is simple declared within the Xaml.cs file as;

```
public Boolean isCorrect = true;
```

An additional question if I'm allowed to whilst I'm here. As far as I understand the use of;

```
Data.isCorrect
```

Gets the value from the cs file, but is there any documentation about this as I've been unable to find anything to do with the Data keyboard as I've simply picked it up through tutorials.